# Kubernetes pod naming convention

Tags: kubernetes, naming

I'm wondering if there is a proper naming convention for generated pod names in Kubernetes. By generated pod names I mean the name displayed in both `kubectl get pods` or, for instance, by querying the heapster api:

```
$ curl -s http://192.168.99.100:32416/api/v1/model/namespaces/kube-system/pods
[
"kube-addon-manager-minikube",
"kube-dns-v20-8gsbl",
"kubernetes-dashboard-tp9kc",
"heapster-kj8hh",
"influxdb-grafana-stg3s"
]

$ curl -s http://192.168.99.100:32416/api/v1/model/namespaces/default/pods
[
"my-nginx-2723453542-065rx"
]
```

If there is no convention (as it looks like) are there any scenario(s) in which the common format: `pod name` + `5 alpha-numeric chars` is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use deployments, for sake of human operators you'll find your pods names as `<replicaset>-<[0-9a-z]{5}>` where replicaset is `<deployment>-<id>`. For kubernetes it self, naming of pods is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that would be the case.

Answer (score 14):

### Naming Convention:

When you create a Deployment, it creates a *replicaset* named as:

`replica-set-name` = `<deployment-name>-<random-string>`

The *replicaset*, in turn, creates the pods adding another **random string*** to them:

`<replica-set-name>-<random-string>`

---

### Example:

```
$ kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx
deployment.apps/nginx created

$ kubectl scale --replicas=3 deploy/nginx 
deployment.extensions/nginx scaled

$ kubectl get replicaset
NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
nginx-554b9c67f9                         3         3         3       96s

$ kubectl get po
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-554b9c67f9-c5cv4                         1/1     Running   0          74s
nginx-554b9c67f9-hjkjq                         1/1     Running   0          74s
nginx-554b9c67f9-wbwdm                         1/1     Running   0          2m7s
```

---

### * Not random at all:

In fact, the "random strings" aren’t completely random at all.

To prevent “bad words”, vowels and the numbers *0*, *1* and *3* were removed from the `rand.String` function (PRs for reference: [#37225](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/37225) and [#50070](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/50070)).

So, the `<random-string>` will be composed by a combination of the following alphanumeric characters: [`bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz2456789`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2183a84feb564582489d56c6570917959f003726/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/rand/rand.go#L80-L90).

Comment: Hey, Do you know if the random string is always a specific size?

Comment: Special thanks for extra info about "bad words" avoiding!

Comment: And it looks like the length of 5 comes from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/22cb31467d20e503a43255cd1868e0885f67f5e8/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/names/generate.go#L45).

Answer (score 9):

if you use deployment then the naming convention as follows:

|--- Deployment: < name >
│`-----`└─ Replica Set: < name >-< rs >
│`--------`└─ Pod: < name >-< rs>-< RandomString >

Answer (score 3):

If you use [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#pods-in-a-statefulset) then the naming convention is:

```
|--- StatefulSets: < name >
│----------└─ Pod: < name >-< ordinal index >
```

e.g. `postgresql-0`